# Build WHERE -> insert_fields() failed

Tags: mysql, sql, odbc

I'm getting the following error on my site:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005' 

[MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.1.73-community]Build WHERE -> insert_fields() failed. 

/new_m_save.asp, line 475
```

Line 475 in new_m_save.asp is:

```
    RS.Open sql,CNopen,3,2      
        RS("PT_peoolaNum")=LastId       
        RS("PT_fatherId")=LastId    
        RS.Update 
RS.Close
```

Comment: Please can you include the creation lines for RS (eg, what the select statement looks like?)

Comment: Have you googled of "ole 80004005'. There's a Mickeysoft page.

Answer (score 0):

What connection mode are you using, put more code here please.

Set the Connection.Mode = 3

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. This is my connection string:    
<code>Session("Conn_Str")  = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3Driver};"
Session("Conn_Str")  =Session("Conn_Str")  & "SERVER=localhost;" 
Session("Conn_Str")  =Session("Conn_Str")  & "DATABASE=xxxxx_db;"
Session("Conn_Str")  =Session("Conn_Str")  & "stmt=SET NAMES 'xxxx';"
Session("Conn_Str")  =Session("Conn_Str")  & "UID=xxxxxx_db;PWD=xxxxxx; OPTION=35;"  

Where do I add the connection mode 3 please?

Comment: can anyone help me with that please?

Comment: shlomi please update your question adding the full ASP code, it will help us to identify the issue and help you. Tkx.